# I am getting an System.IO.IOException while uploading a file to Amazon cloud server

Tags: asp.net, filestream

I am getting 
 **Error**

> {System.IO.IOException: Unable to write data to the transport
>   connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in
>   your host machine. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   established connection was aborted by the software in your host
>   machine

I am trying to upload a file to Amazon cloud server. It works smooth for small files, but throws this exception when I try to upload a file of about a GB.

**Code**

```
void writeStreamToService(S3Request request, long reqDataLen, Stream inputStream, Stream requestStream)
        {
            if (inputStream != null)
            {
                long current = 0;
                // Reset the file stream's position to the starting point
                inputStream.Position = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[this.config.BufferSize];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    current += bytesRead;
                    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    if (request != null)
                    {
                        request.OnRaiseProgressEvent(bytesRead, current, reqDataLen);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You'll have to contact Amazon I imagine.

Comment: @asawyer: thanks for the response.
**An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"**
I believe its an error from my side Since my machine is the host and it is aborting.

Comment: I'm confused - your machine is an amazon cloud host server?

Comment: No its not, I think I misunderstood. This error means that the abort operation is happening from Amazon server?
This works smooth for smaller files though, I never faced any problems while uploading.

Comment: The amazon server is rejecting the connection - it is the host, you are the client.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was actually the anti Virus in my PC that was blocking the buffer memory Overflow, Disabling it got the job done :) 
Thanks for your help @asawyer!